# How do I set state in React when there is no class or constructor?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm looking at the default demo React code in https://codesandbox.io/s/new, which comes out like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

const App = () => <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />;

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is different than many of the other examples I've seen, which usually have something more like:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...};
  }
  render() {...}
}
```

Since the codesandbox example doesn't have a class or a constructor, I don't have a place to put `this.state`. So how and where would I add a state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**App** is a stateless component.

You can just convert **App** to a class if you want to have state.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...};
  }
  render() {
    return <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is an article which might help:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/stateful-vs-stateless-functional-components-in-react--cms-29541

There is a section titled **Class Components vs. Functional Components**

Answer (score 9):

Starting with React 16.8, function components can have state. You don't need a class anymore.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; // need to import useState

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0); // initialize state

  function changeState() { 
    setCount(count + 1); // change state
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Count: {count}</h2>
      <button onClick={changeState}>Change State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full example https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-newton-18bc9

useState() is an example of a [Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.

Comment: @ BurritoWhere is setCount defined? is this a callback that can have any name and you just pass it the new updated portion of the state? I see many example and always this second argument is having different values...TY

Comment: @landed It's a setter function returned by useState() (you could call it whatever you want), which lets you update the state value, in this case count (which you can also call whatever you want). More info at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

```
const App = () => <Hello name='CodeSandbox' />;
```

That is an `stateless` component.

The only way to interact with that kind of components is through `props`.

```
const App = ({ name }) => <Hello name={name} />;

render(<App name='CodeSandbox' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways on how to use state without a constructor or class component:

- [Class field declarations](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/react-alternative-class-component-syntax) which enables you to omit the class constructor, but still to use state in a React class component.
- A [higher-order component](https://www.robinwieruch.de/gentle-introduction-higher-order-components/) or [render prop component](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-render-props-pattern/) which manages state on behalf of the enhanced component.

  - The higher-order component `withState` from [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) that manages state on behalf of the enhanced component.

You can find out more about the different solutions for managing state without a class component over [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor/).